# What is an exhaustive list of "all the things" in vim?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for a list of the basics, for instance, not a list of all the plugins, but plugin would be on my list; here is what I have so far help me out if I've missed anything or if I've mis-named anything:

- .vimrc
- vimscript functions
- regular expressions
- key mappings
- plugins
- swap file
- tabs
- panes
- selection ranges
- ! to run bash commands from vim (whatever that's called)

Comment: For terminology, just refer to the very comprehensive `:help`. For an introduction / overview of Vim, there are tons of web pages, vimcasts.org, or even a number of books.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vim has a user manual ([`:help usr_toc`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_toc.txt.html)) that covers all of these topics.  It's good to browse through in general and can be a good starting point when you're thinking `How do I do X in Vim?`.  Opening up that help and doing a search is a good place to start.

Another important item for using the help is to get used to using the context-specific help -- [`:help help-context`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/help.txt.html#help-context).  Some help topics are ambiguous unless you include the proper context.

That being said, here are the sections about the specific topics you bring up.

### .vimrc

[`:help vimrc-intro`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_05.txt.html#vimrc-intro) describes the basic info about where the vimrc lives and provides some example settings.  Since the vimrc is just another vim script, the scripting section of the user manual ([`:help usr_41`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html)) is also useful.

### vimscript functions

These are covered in the scripting part of the manual mentioned above, but there are specific sections on using functions ([`:help 41.6`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#41.6)) and defining functions ([`:help 41.7`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#41.6)).

### regular expressions

[`:help usr_27`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_27.txt.html) describes searching and covers some regular expressions, but [`:help pattern.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html) is the canonical section of the reference manual for all things related to Vim regular expressions

### key mappings

[`:help 40.1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_40.txt.html#40.1) covers all the high level details and [`:help key-mapping`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#key-mapping) goes into all the nitty-gritty details.

### plugins

The basic `how` of adding a plugin to your configuration is described at ([`:help 05.4`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_05.txt.html#05.4)) but typically people use a [plugin manager](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/614/15) to handle this now.  Plugin managers provide, at a minimum, better isolation of plugins and the ability to easily enable/disable plugins.

### swap file

Swap files provide a means of recovery, as described in [`:help usr_11`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_11.txt.html).  In a [related answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/179/15), I've described this as well as ways to manage swap files.

### tabs (tab pages)

Tab pages are basically viewports, or ways to organize windows.  [`:help 08.9`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_08.txt.html#08.9) gives a brief overview of what a tab page is, but [`:help tab-page`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html#tab-page) gives more info on how to actually use them.

### panes (split windows)

Split windows ([`:help 08.1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_08.txt.html#08.1)) provide a way to view multiple buffers (or different views of the same buffer) at once.  When Vim mentions a horizontal or vertical split, this is referring to the orientation of the actual line that splits two windows, not the orientation of the windows in reference to each other.

### selection ranges (command ranges)

I think you're referring to the ranges automatically added to a command when you press `:` in visual mode (`:'<,'>`), however ranges can describe much more than just the visual selection.

[`:help 10.3`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_10.txt.html#10.3) describes the general usage, but [`:help cmdilne-ranges`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt#cmdline-ranges) has all the details.

### ! (running external commands)

[`:help 21.2`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_21.txt#21.2) describes the various ways that external programs can be used -- directly executing one-off commands (`:!`), reading output from a command into the buffer (`:r !{cmd}`), sending the buffer to a command as in put (`:w !{cmd}`), and filtering a buffer through a program (`:[range]!{cmd}`).

Answer (score 11):

The most comprehensive *single-page* reference is probably:

```
:help quickref
```

Comment: this is fantastic. i should scan the share docs more often.

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is usually called the vimdoc. An HTML version can be found [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_toc.html). It can also be accessed from within vim by entering `:help`.

For more information on a specific topic or key combination you would use `:h pattern` where `pattern` is the topic or key cord you are interested in. If you're not sure exactly what something is called you can use `:h patt` followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to get a list of topics that may match.

For a more detailed explanation on how to use help see [this wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Learn_to_use_help).