# Why are swap files so big?

Tags: swap-file

I open a file with vim, vim creates a swap file. Though I have not done any single edit on my file, the swap file has significant size, sometimes bigger than the size of the original file.

For example, original file = 1.4K, swap = 12K.
What's written inside the swap file that makes it bigger than the original file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap files appear to contain some basic information about your computer (try opening the swap file in vim! I found the vim version, pc name, file path&name, utf encoding and some other "settings" stored) as well as a whole lot of "nothing".
The "nothing" is actually a significant amount of padded null characters `^@` (which I presume is used as a placeholder for the swap file to include other relevant information).

As such, swap files aren't actually "big", they just have some base information making them a bit bigger than the original file. As your files get larger, the % difference between the original file and the swap file becomes less significant.

Answer (score 1):

Vim stores the things you changed in a swap file. Using the original file you started from plus the swap file you can mostly recover your work.

[For a detail of What is the purpose of swap files?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/177/what-is-the-purpose-of-swap-files), follow the link.

Comment: I know the purpose of the swap file. But it gets to that size right after I open the file. No changes at all were made. I realize that not only the changes are stored there but also some meta information, like pid of the editing process etc. But it wouldn't make the swap as big.

Comment: Well, it seems that yes.
It would be necessary to analyze the source code of the VIM to know exactly what information it saves or reserves space.